# Bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that preserves lexicographic order?

Tags: order-theory

Is there a bijective mapping $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that preserves lexicographic order?

That's to say, we'd need to have $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) \leq f(y_1, \dots, y_n)$ iff $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \leq_{lex} (y_1, \dots, y_n)$.

In the same ballpark: what would be a formal argument that such an order exists, or not (or some hint to how the formal argument would look like)?

Comment: Even in the case $n=2$, you would have to be able to fit uncountably many disjoint nondegenerate intervals into the real line, wouldn't you? That's not possible...

Comment: This is definitely not abstract algebra. I'd be tempted to tag it as topology, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MPW: You can go further. You can't have an uncountable partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into disjoint measurable subsets of positive measure. So assuming such a function $f$ exists, for fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$, is the set $f(\left\{x\right\}\times\mathbb{R})$ of positive (outer) measure?

Comment: @Matt: I think that because $f$ is order-preserving and bijective, it must be the case that $f(\{x\}\times[a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$ and likewise for the corresponding open intervals. So not only is such a set measurable, it really is an interval.

Comment: @MPW: You're right. If $f(x',y')=r\in (f(a),f(b))$, then $f(x,a)<f(x',y')\Rightarrow x\leq x'$ and $f(x,b)>f(x',y')\Rightarrow x=x'$. Repeating the argument for the second variable yields $y'\in (a,b)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in the case $n=2$, you would have to be able to fit uncountably many disjoint nondegenerate intervals into the real line. Indeed, because $f$ is order-preserving and bijective, it must be the case that $f(\{x\}\times[a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$ and likewise for the corresponding open intervals.

Since every open interval contains a rational number, we cannot have uncountably many such disjoint intervals.

(après MPW)