# Is there a bijective mapping $f:\mathbb{N}^2→\mathbb{N}$ that preserves lexicographic order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a bijective mapping $f:\mathbb{N}^2→\mathbb{N}$ that preserves lexicographic order?

I know that it is impossyble for the case $f:\mathbb{R}^2→\mathbb{R}$ ( here [Bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that preserves lexicographic order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857315/bijection-from-mathbbrn-to-mathbbr-that-preserves-lexicographic-order?rq=1)) but seems  I cant use the same arguments.

Comment: Look at where the pairs $(0,n)$ are sent.  Now where is the image of $(1,0)$ relative to them?

Comment: But I dont know what is the map $f$

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Let $a_n = f(0,n)$.  Then you can say certain things about the $a_n$'s; namely, they're increasing.  So where is $f(1,0)$ relative to the $a_n$'s?

Comment: Well.. I think that for some $n$  must be $a_n > f(1,0)$.

Comment: Oh..But $(1,0)>(0,n)$?

Comment: Yup!  And these are some more characters.

Comment: I see now,  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. The order type of $N^2$ under lexicographic ordering is $\omega^2$.

Comment: is there more elementary  and direct  proof without involving of the $\omega$?

Comment: The more elementary proof is in the comments to the question.